# How can I change the value of a variable when I compile using ng build --prod?

Tags: angular

My scenario is the following, I have a file called `config.ts` where I have stored the url of my web services:

/config/webservices.ts

```
export const URL = "http://localhost:3000/login";
```

I want to know if there is any way for some variable to dynamically get a value according to whether I am in `development` or `production`
something like that:

```
var ENVIRONMET= ENV.getEnvironment //if is development http://localhost:3000/ else https://myapp.herokuapp/;
export const URL = ${"ENVIRONMET}login";
```

so when i run

```
ng build --prod
```

will automatically change the value from `ENVIRONMET` to `https://myapp.herokuapp/` otherwise as I am in `development` it will use: `http://localhost:3000/`

I don't know if it is possible.

how can I do it? thank you.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have the value in environment.ts which angular replace for production builds with environment.prod.ts.

For example in environment.ts content can be:

```
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   url: 'http://localhost:3000',
};
```

In environment.prod.ts content can be :

```
export const environment = {
   production: true,
   url: 'https://myapp.herokuapp/',
};
```

If you would rather have a separate config.ts, create a config.prod.ts in a similar way, and add the file replacements in angular.json

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            },
            {
              "replace": "src/config.ts",
              "with": "src/config.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 files `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` in `src/environments` folder.

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  URL: 'https://myapp.herokuapp/'
};
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  URL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

And make sure in your `angular.json` below lines available.

```
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
```

And the in your `config.ts` use this way.

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export class Config {
    public static URL = environment.URL;
}
```

It will dynamically bind URL.